# How to create stored procedure in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error, declare

I know Microsoft sql server and I think this codes doesn't contain an error. But Mysql thow an exeption which I Couldn't undestant. Is anybody can explain it for me and 
please,give me mysql function,view,stored procedure examples website name

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertEmployee
(
 Employee_Name nvarchar(20),
 Employee_Surname nvarchar(20),
 Department_Name nvarchar(20)
)
BEGIN
declare Department_Id int; /*error*/
select Id into Department_Id from tblDepartment where      tblDepartment.Department_Name=Department_Name;
insert into tblVeri(Employee_Name,Employee_Surname,Department_Id)     values(Employee_Name,Employee_Surname,Department_Id);
END /*error*/
```

Comment: You need to provide a delimiter at the beginning and close the end as `end;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define `IN` for the parameters.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertEmployee 
(
IN Employee_Name nvarchar(20), 
IN Employee_Surname nvarchar(20), 
IN Department_Name nvarchar(20)
)
BEGIN
declare Department_Id INT;

select Id into Department_Id from tblDepartment WHERE tblDepartment.Department_Name=Department_Name;
insert into tblVeri(Employee_Name,Employee_Surname,Department_Id)     VALUES(Employee_Name,Employee_Surname,Department_Id);

END;
```